# sql count or sum?

Tags: sql

I'm a newbie programmer, I want to sum a value of employee's attendance record
Anyway, what should I choose? COUNT or SUM?

I tried to use COUNT functions like this...

```
SELECT COUNT(jlh_sakit) AS sakit FROM rekap_absen
```

It shows value changed to "1" for 1 Record only.

And I try to use SUM functions like this...

```
SELECT SUM(jlh_sakit) AS sakit FROM rekap_absen
```

It shows all values changed ALL value to "1"

I want to display only 1 person for each sum
(e.g : John (2 sick, 2 permissions, 1 alpha)

Can you help me please?

Comment: Use SUM with group by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using any aggregate function like min/max/sum/count you should use group by. Now your question says "what should I choose? COUNT or SUM?" Assuming you have person_name, jlh_sakit which means sick/permission/alpha in your case you could use

```
select person_name, count(jhl_sakit) as attribute
from rekap_absen 
group by person
```

This will give you output like:

`person_name attribute
John 2
King 5`

Comment: then how to display it into an ActiveReport?

Comment: That's a follow up question and you need to create a new question by tagging it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In order to sum by specified column, use group by statement.

```
SELECT SUM(sick),SUM(alpha),SUM(permissions),person FROM rekap_absen group by person
```

It will group your sums according to person. 
You may name your sums like: 
    SELECT SUM(sick) as sick,SUM(alpha) as alpha,SUM(permissions) as permissions,person FROM rekap_absen group by person

Assuming that you have table rekap_absen with columns: person,sick,alpha,permissions